# Light up a Star (Photoshop)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, illustrator-effects

How can I add light to the star on the right hand side (2B) in order to achieve the desired result (2A - picture on the left)?

[image]

How would you do that in Photoshop / Illustrator?
Do you know good tutorials I can find about this topic on the internet?

Thank you and kind regards,
Silvan

Comment: That wasn't done in Photoshop or any image manipulation app, it was done in 3D modelling software.

Comment: Ok. But would it be possible to achieve a comparable result in Photoshop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is very likely done in 3D modelling software, where it's just a matter of modelling a light inside it.
You can get something a bit like it in Photoshop using exposure & inner glow.

First separate out the glass elements to a new layer. Increase exposure to make it lighter, then add a little inner glow which appears to make the light slightly stronger in the centre, fading to the edges.

This is a very, very rough attempt on just a few panels…

[image]

I'm not convinced, even allowing for the inaccuracies in my initial selection. I merged down the original exposure separation so I can't show the steps properly. Here are a couple of the steps.
<sub>Click for full size</sub>

[image]

[image]